What force expels the negative charged particle in carbon 14?
What force expels the negative charged particle from carbon 14 as radiation ? Is it electromagnetic force, strong force or weak force ??

What force expels Sun's radiation that travels at the speed of light ?

The beta decay is mediated by the weak force.

If solar corpuscular radiation is at it's strongest at the Sun's equator, then what force is allowed to be at it's strongest at equator to expel  ionized radiation ? In earth, "Only" Clockwise gyres of plastic in the sea just north of equator at 0-60 degrees on observed earth & anti Clockwise gyres just "south" of equator at 0-60 degrees strongly suggests perpendicular anti clockwise rotations of electromagnetic force pushing metal impurities in sea ? Gives versa for near but North of equator ? Only gyres near equator on earth suggests electromagnetic force strongest at equator ?

Please elaborate by meaning mediated by weak force ? Expelled by weak force ?

"Or" do you mean weak force becomes less, allowing less attraction, giving detachment of negative particle?? But considering speeds of radiation (speed of light ?) then expulsion by force must be strong in manner ? As in expulsion by force ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

surely, if a neutron has a dipole magnetic field, then expulsion of a negative particle (that always has an electromagnetic field of its own) would have to "also" expel a positive to balance out for that neutron ? Are protons "also always" created; or only now & then ??

please excuse me, am trying to clarify by saying; How was weak force detected ? Was "same" polarity of electrostatic force "ruled out" for kinetic expulsion of negative electron ?

To elaborate on negative particle always having electromagnetic force of its own, I mean negative particle being an electron that has an electromagnetic force of its own.

Are positives in a generator made by reversing rotation of generator ? If true, then surely this implies perpendicular rotations of electromagnetic field forces rotation of electrons in "same" direction as rotation of generator ? So "same" direction of rotation of electron as proton's rotation could mean electron "not" crossing proton's lines of electromagnetic "attraction", allowing electron in "high" orbit giving negatives on surface ? But if electron forced in "opposite" rotation to proton then it crosses proton's lines of em force attraction= low orbit electron gives positives ?

Physicists still secretly think electron has spin because of electron's "constant" angular momentum around proton. But spin would be over speed of light. So physicists propose stretching electron as a wave ? From comment above using the generator, then physicist's proposal of electron stretched as a wave & not a particle orbiting a proton surely wouldn't be possible because electron would constantly cross proton's lines of electromagnetic force "attraction", giving "low" orbit electrons that gives positives on surfaces (does deuterium have positives on surface with low orbit electrons ?) ?

What is this electromagnetic force "within" electron that pushes an electron to speed of light ? It has no mass & does not have infinite energy to propel electron, whilst travelling against resistances, to speed of light. Solar radiation travels at speed of light. Is it because electromagnetic force pushes radiation to speed of light ? What is inside electron, seen as electromagnetic force coming from electron ? Is it separate from electron, or part of electron ? Surely electromagnetic "loop" that "recycles" em field needs proton's em field & electron's em field for attraction & repulsion loop

Can you even confine an electron to a C-14 nucleus? How big is a C-14 nucleus, and what is the Compton wavelength of an electron?

Your comments are very confused. Electrons do not travel at the speed of light!

When an electron is created in beta decay a proton is also created, and so is an antineutrino. There is also energy released in the form of kinetic energy of those three daughter particles.

You’ve asked 25 new questions in comments. Please don’t do that. Ask questions in posts.

@PM 2Ring I stand corrected. Had asked question in the past & got this. Made me think above as speed of light !
https://www.ganpatiengineering.com/blog/how-fast-does-electricity-travel-through-copper-wire/#:~:text=The%20speed%20of%20electricity%20through,or%20186%2C000%20miles%20per%20second.

@PM 2Ring Read Electromagnetic force can push electrons to 99% speed of light. So now assume 99% is achieved in particle accelerator. Annoyed with engineering site; "The speed of electricity through a copper wire is approximately 98-99% of the speed of light in a vacuum, which equates to about 300,000,000 meters per second or 186,000 miles per second." very misleading, which led my enquiry down wrong path !
https://www.ganpatiengineering.com/blog/how-fast-does-electricity-travel-through-copper-wire/#:~:text=The%20speed%20of%20electricity%20through,or%20186%2C000%20miles%20per%20second.

From that Ganpati link, "Signal velocity, representing the speed of the electric wave or signal, can approach the speed of light in a vacuum. However, the actual movement of electrons, known as electron drift, is considerably slower."

The electrons emitted by C-14 can have speeds upto 0.64c, but rhe mean speed is around 0.4c.

The electron is "created", via the weak force, with a large amount of kinetic energy. The energy is greater than the electrostatic energy attracting it to the nucleus, so it escapes.

How is weak force detected ? Is weak force just repulsion energy that's greater than electrostatic energy ? But how is weak force detected ? Was "same" polarity of electrostatic force "ruled out" for kinetic expulsion of negative electron ??

Someone please elaborate how weak force was detected ?

@andrew The weak force was originally postulated as the cause of beta decay.

So it's theoretical & not actually measured. Interesting. I thank you for your reply. From above, concerning spin of electron would be faster than speed of light, but physicists still think spin of electron must be happening because of "constant" angular momentum of electron orbiting proton. If my comment above, suggesting proposed spin stretched as a wave likely not possible. "If" that electromagnetic force can push electron to speed of light whilst pushing against resistances, then, if absent of resistances, "why" would Einstein state electrons can't exceed speed of light without resistances

@andrew Not macroscopically measured: according to the theory it's observed to be weak because it has very short range. But there's a quantitative theory based on measurements. Perhaps it shouldn't be considered a force at all, but the definition of "force" in physics is shifty and contextual. In the microscopic theory it's closely associated with the electromagnetic force, so perhaps it should be considered a force. The Universe doesn't care what words you use, nor how you wish to model what goes on.

Meaning, if superconductor expels electromagnetic force (Meissner effect), then does that mean electrons are only at the surface of superconductor because electrons have their own electromagnetic force ?? Without electromagnetic force inside a superconductor (Meissner effect), how can electrons be dislodged from protons ?If electromagnetic force is constantly expelled outside of superconductor surface, then surely do force would limit speed of electron to speed of light ? If AC current constantly reverses flow of electrons forward & backwards direction, then electron speed constant ??

Interesting in your answer.

Meaning, the electromagnetic force constantly reversing flow of electrons backwards & forwards in AC current surely limits electron speed to speed of light, but constant speed of light ???

@andrew The drift velocity of electrons in a current-carrying wire is very slow: it has nothing to do with the speed of light.

An experiment of using electromagnetic force to push something without any resistances or resistances from other electromagnetic forces ?? But that would need something free of earth's magnetic fields & other free floating particles emitting their own em  fields ???

Then how slow or fast are electrons in a wire ??

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity#Numerical_example

Then I take it the speed of electrons in a copper wire are a proportion of the speed of light ? But surely that fraction of speed of light is sizeable if a telephone call across the globe is only slight delay ?

I stand corrected. My apologies. just now read the electromagnetic force can achieve 50-99% speed of light. But drift velocity (resistances within wire?) within wire reduce speed of  electron to much much slower speeds ??
